# MySQL order results by the sum of two relations count(*)

Tags: mysql

I would like to order the results by the count(*) of two related tables entries.

So I would like to get the top ordered user IDs that have more comments + posts interactions.

---

User Table:
<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd> <kbd>**`Name`**</kbd>  <kbd>**`...`**</kbd>
<kbd>`1`</kbd>  <kbd>`Jonh`</kbd>  
<kbd>`2`</kbd>  <kbd>`Mark`</kbd>  
<kbd>`3`</kbd>  <kbd>`King`</kbd>  
<kbd>`4`</kbd>  <kbd>`Doe`</kbd>

Post Table:
<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd> <kbd>**`USER_ID`**</kbd><kbd>**`...`**</kbd>
<kbd>`1`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>      
<kbd>`2`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>      
<kbd>`3`</kbd>  <kbd>`3`</kbd>      
<kbd>`4`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>

Comment Table:
<kbd>**`ID`**</kbd> <kbd>**`USER_ID`**</kbd><kbd>**`...`**</kbd>
<kbd>`1`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>      
<kbd>`2`</kbd>  <kbd>`3`</kbd>      
<kbd>`3`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd>      
<kbd>`4`</kbd>  <kbd>`4`</kbd>

---

Ordered by POSTs count(*):

```
SELECT user.*, COUNT(post.user_id) AS count FROM user
LEFT JOIN post ON user.id = post.user_id
GROUP BY user.id
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Ordered by COMMENTs count(*)

```
SELECT user.*, COUNT(comment.user_id) AS count FROM user
LEFT JOIN comment ON user.id = comment.user_id
GROUP BY user.id
ORDER BY count DESC
```

---

Ordered by POSTs + COMMENTs count(*)

Expected Result:
user_id: 1 (four interactions), 3 (two interactions), 4 (one interaction)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(interact.user_id)
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN  ( SELECT user_id  FROM post
             UNION ALL
             SELECT user_id  FROM comment 
           ) interact
 ON u.user_id = interact.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

If you want more detail can use conditional count

```
SELECT u.*, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN source = 'p' then 1 END) as total_p,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN source = 'c' then 1 END) as total_c,
       COUNT(interact.user_id) as total_interact
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN  ( SELECT user_id, 'p' as source  FROM post
             UNION ALL
             SELECT user_id, 'c' as source  FROM comment 
           ) interact
 ON u.user_id = interact.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Comment: User Table 200k data, Post Table 500k data, Comment Table 900k data. I tried in the real database but both query never finish.

Comment: do you have index for user_id on all tables?

Comment: Yes. User (Primary Key), Post (Foreign Key + Index), Comment (Foreign Key + Index).

Comment: can you share the explain plan ?

Comment: well I guess no :(